# jQuery separating multiple event functions among the same variable

Tags: jquery, events, onclick, event-listener, mousedown

I'm making a pixel art maker within a table. I'm having trouble separating the draw function from the erase function. I have tried many methods, but am finding that no matter what I can only get one to work (draw or erase).

Here's the bit of code that I'm working with. There is also another issue in there with the click and drag to draw function not working.

```
var eraserIsActive = false;
let mouseEvents = 0;
let paint;
let cPicker = $("#colorPicker").val();

$('#eraser').click(function() {
  eraserIsActive = true;
});
$('#colorizer').click(function() {
  eraserIsActive = false;
})

if (eraserIsActive = true) {
  paint = "white";
} else {
  paint = cPicker;
  }
 canvas.on('mousedown', 'td', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   mouseEvents === 1;
     $(event.target).css('background-color', paint);
  })
 if (mouseEvents === 1) {
   canvas.on('mouseenter', 'td', function(event) {
    $(event.target).css('background-color', paint);
   })
 }
}
```

[Full version on Codepen here](https://codepen.io/MarilynL/pen/RMLbqW)

Comment: What’s the comparison *$(this) === isActive;* inside *$(“button”).click()* handler?

Comment: I guess I was supposed to be declaring the variable isActive outside as true or false like `var eraserIsActive = false;
let mouseEvents = 0;
let paint;
let cPicker = $("#colorPicker").val();
  
$('#eraser').click(function() {
  eraserIsActive = true;
});
  $('#colorizer').click(function() {
   eraserIsActive = false;
  })

if (eraserIsActive = true) {
  paint = "white";
} else {
  paint = cPicker;
}` but its still wrong